# Waiting for several Requests to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

At my pageload I have to retrieve three JSONs (for `loadJSON()` please see **PS**)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadJSON("JSON1.json",function(json){
        json1 = json:
        console.log("JSON1 loaded");
    });
    loadJSON("JSON2.json",function(json){
        json2 = json:
        console.log("JSON2 loaded");
    });
    loadJSON("JSON3.json",function(json){        
        json3 = json:
        console.log("JSON3 loaded");
    });

    //doing stuff after all three have loaded (PSEUDO:)
    waitTillFinished(doingStuff(json1, json2, json3));
});
```

Then I need to run a function combining the results of the three JSONs (the `doingStuff` function) therefore it has to wait till all three have finished. 
I though of a function that does the active waiting and fire a callback, e.g. `doingStuff`.

**How can I do that?**

I am in search for some kind of semaphore pattern here. How is this typically done in JS?

**Already Tried:**

A jQuery construction:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.when(
    loadJSON("JSON1.json",function(json){
        json1 = json;
        console.log("JSON1 loaded");
    }),
    loadJSON("JSON2.json",function(json){
        json2 = json;
        console.log("JSON2 loaded");
    }),
    loadJSON("JSON3.json",function(json){        
        json3 = json;
        console.log("JSON3 loaded");
    })
  ).then(
    doingStuff(json1, json2, json3);
  );
});
```

This does not wait for the calls to finish. That is totally understood, since loadJSON function have finished, only the callbacks haven't fired yet.

A use of "status-semaphores"

```
var status1 = $.getJSON("JSON1.json"[..]); //shortend [..]
var status2 = $.getJSON("JSON2.json"[..]); //shortend [..]
var status3 = $.getJSON("JSON3.json"[..]); //shortend [..]

status1.complete(function(){
  status2.complete(function(){
    status3.complete(doingStuff(json1, json2, json3)
  }
}
```

This does work, but it does not scale. For two calls it would have considered this solution, three already has a smell. But I expect to get even more Calls when the app is growing.

**PS:**
The `loadJSON()` function is a helper function for loading and logging the request stuff:

```
function loadJSON(requestURL, callback){
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', requestURL, true); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xobj.readyState == 4){
          if(xobj.status == 200){
              callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));            
          } else {
              console.error(xobj.statusText);
          }
      }
  }
  xobj.onerror = function(e){
      console.error(xobj.statusText);
  }
  xobj.send();
}
```

Comment: here is the concept Promise.all, search it in yout framework( jquery...), and MDN is https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all

Answer (score 3):

Your code using `$.when` would work **if** `loadJSON` returned a promise/deferred, like jQuery's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) does. So:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.when(
    $.getJSON("JSON1.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON2.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON3.json")
  ).then(function(data1, data2, data3) { // Note naming, once they're parsed (which
    doingStuff(data1, data2, data3);     // getJSON does), they're not JSON anymore
  });
});
```

or actually, we don't need the wrapper function if `doingStuff` takes the three parameters in the order we pass the calls to `$.when`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.when(
    $.getJSON("JSON1.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON2.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON3.json")
  ).then(doingStuff);
});
```

Note I've used `then` instead of `done`. Unusually, the `then` callback will be called with discrete arguments for each result (whereas a normal `then` calls its callback with just one argument). Note that if you use `done` instead, you'll get three discrete arguments, but they're *arrays* where each array has the data, textStatus, and jqXHR object that resulted from the `$.getJSON` call.

Or we could use `Promise.all` (on any major modern browser):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  Promise.all([
    $.getJSON("JSON1.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON2.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON3.json")
  ]).then(function(results) {
    doingStuff(results[0], results[1], results[2]);
  });
});
```

Note we pass the promises as an array, and get back an array. In ES2015+ we could use destructuring in the parameter list of the `then` callback:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  Promise.all([
    $.getJSON("JSON1.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON2.json"),
    $.getJSON("JSON3.json")
  ]).then(([data1, data2, data3]) => {
    doingStuff(data1, data2, data3);
  });
});
```